# Blank page when using dynamic routes, normal routes work fine - REACT, REACT ROUTER

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Trying to implement dynamic routes but I can't seem to access the link in production, I am getting a blank page. However, everything works fine in development and if I remove the "/:id" from the path. What am I doing wrong? In package.json I have set homepage property to ".".

App.js

```
 import Information from './pages/Auth/Information/Information';
 import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

 function App() {
  return(
  <div className="App">
   <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="someother" element={<Someother />} />
            <Route exact path='/Information/:id' element={<Information />} />
            
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
   </div>
  )
 }
```

Information.js

```
const Information = () => {
return (
        <div>Hello</div>
)
}

export default Information;
```

Comment: How are you running/serving/hosting the app in production? You likely just need to configure whatever server/hosting service to serve the root index.html file for all page requests the app handles. See the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to gather a sense of what different servers need specifically setup/configured for them to accomplish this.

Comment: @DrewReese atm I'm just running the build locally and facing the same issue

Comment: Doesn't your post say "everything works fine in development"? How are you running/serving/hosting the app that causes the issue?

Comment: @DrewReese  package.json has the build:  "rimraf ./build && react-scripts build && rimraf ./build/**/*.map" script so I just do npm run build and then serve it using serve -s build command

Comment: I guess the `serve -s build` command needs to do the thing I described above with serving the index.html file. I don't know if I'd be much help from here though.